# NHibernate - Stored Procedure - Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, nhibernate

I have a stored procedure that is performing inserts on a table via a Windows Service. It potentially inserts quite a bit of data.

There is also a website that allows users to enter data into the same table that the stored procedure is inserting into. The issue is that NHibernate uses HILO, not SQL Identity, therefore the fact that the stored procedure is entering data unbeknownst to NHibernate creates a scenario where NHibernate attempts to enter a record using an Id that has already been used.

Does anyone have any ideas how to remedy this? Can I update the `next_hi` field, or is that a bad idea? My other option is to wrest control away from NHibernate for all inserts into this table.

By the way, the problem is sporadic. Probably correlates/coincides with App Pool recycles if I had to guess.

Edit (Possible Solution): I've been told by one of our resident NHibernate experts that if the Proc updates the "next_hi" field, then our problems will be solved. That is an easy solution that I can get on board with. I will update this post to let everyone know how that works out.

Edit 2: The solution above does not seem to be working. My thought at this point is that you shouldn't use HILO if you intend to have another system that interacts with your database.

Comment: use sql identity with nhibernate?

Answer (score 2):

you should centralize the id generation either by having just one service doing the nhibernate insertion or by moving it to the logic of the store procedure

Comment: That is a good idea. However, it isn't really possible in the near-term.

Comment: My thought is that the database should manage id assignment, not the ORM.

Comment: i agree with you @DonRolling that the database should be the one handling the id